# Gulp Watchify not printing build time for js files

Tags: javascript, gulp, watchify

My gulp file seems to be running fine, and Watchify is working when I make changes to my *app.js* file or my sass files. This is what happens when I run the `gulp` command:

```
myname$ gulp
[17:06:06] Requiring external module babel-core/register
[17:06:08] Using gulpfile ~/some/path/gulpfile.babel.js
[17:06:08] Starting 'watch-styles'...
[17:06:08] Finished 'watch-styles' after 13 ms
[17:06:08] Starting 'scripts'...
[17:06:08] Finished 'scripts' after 42 ms
[17:06:08] Starting 'default'...
[17:06:08] Finished 'default' after 22 μs
```

The thing is, these times only show up the first time I do `gulp`. After I've run the `gulp` command, the build times don't show when I make a change to my JS file. It does tell me build times for sass files, but not for my JS. As I said before, Watchify is working and the new output files are created, but there is no feedback in my terminal that tells me how long it took. In fact, there is no message at all with my JS changes.

Here is my [gulpfile](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5829841d1fc7d1897919).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you change the definitions of your default and watch tasks to this you will get your expected result:

```
gulp.task('watch-styles', () => {
  gulp.watch([].concat(sassDirs.src, jsDirs.src), ['scripts', 'styles'])
})

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'scripts'])
```